# Petrol Pumps circular tour

Tags: c++, algorithm

Problem:

> Suppose there is a circle. There are n petrol pumps on that circle.
>   You are given two sets of data.
>
> 1. The amount of petrol that petrol pump will give.
> 2. Distance from that petrol pump to the next petrol pump.
>
> Calculate the first point from where a truck will be able to complete
>   the circle

I just solved the problem. I want to know if I solved the problem correctly.

Algorithm:

I started from starting point and I tried adding rest of the petrol left travelling the distance. if value is < 0 and if we reach start again then no solution exists. otherwise keep looping till you reach the end. End is always start + 1; Also I know the algorithm O(n). Can some one also explain using a good logic how its O(n).

```
int PPT(int P[], int D[], int N)
{

   int start = 0, end = 1, cur_ptr = P[0] - D[0], i = start;

   while(start != end)
   {

      if(cur_ptr < 0)
      {
         start = (i + 1) % N;
         end = (start + 1) % N;
         cur_ptr = 0;
         if(start == 0) return -1; // if start again becomes 0 then no solution exists

      } 
      i = (i + 1) % N;

      cur_ptr += P[i] - D[i];
   }
}
```

Comment: I assume `P[]` is the amount of petrol a pump will give and `D[]` is the distance from that pump to the next pump. Could you explain what is `cur_ptr`? and how are you calculating amount of petrol to the distance traveled?

Comment: Can I assume that `P[]` contains the distance for which the user has enough petrol? This would make it easier to compare `D[]` and `P[]`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [algorithm for truck moving around a circle of gas stations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286849/algorithm-for-truck-moving-around-a-circle-of-gas-stations)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`start != end` always holds. Therefore, your algorithm produces an infinite loop if there is a solution. Furthermore, I don't understand, why `end` should be `start + 1`.

Here is another approach:

Consider the following function:

[image: remaining petrol function]

This function calculates the remaining petrol just before arriving at pump `i`. The function can be visualized as follows:

[image: remaining petrol function]

The function starts at `petrol = 0`. You see that this configuration is not valid, because at pump 4 the remaining petrol is negative. Furthermore, there is a solution, because the remaining petrol at the last pump (again the start pump) is positive.

What happens, if we choose a different start? The basic shape of the function remains the same. It is just moved to the left. Furthermore, because the function starts at `petrol = 0`, the function is decreased by `C(start)`. The remaining fuel at the end does not play a role in this case, because it would increase the current petrol.

The task is to find a `start` that allows all `C(i)` to be positive. This is obviously the case for the minimal `C(i)`, in this case for `start = 4`.

Calculating the function `C(i)` can be done iteratively, and therefore, in linear time. You iterate once from 0 to N. The minimum can be found during this iteration in constant time (by comparing with the current minimum). Therefore, the overall time complexity is `O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the solution you provide is correct. Whenever `cur_ptr` is greater than 0, you are not updating the variable `end`. Therefore, suppose if at every station `P[i] > D[i]`, the loop will keep running till infinity.

Besides a few more changes, I believe you need to add `end = (end + 1) % N;` somewhere. I have modified the code and it gives the correct solution.

```
    int PPT(int[] P, int[] D, int N)
    {
        int start = 0, end = 1, cur_ptr = P[0] - D[0];
        bool none = false;

        while (start != end)
        {
            if (cur_ptr < 0)
            {
                start = (start + 1) % N;
                if (start == 0)    // all stations have been traveled but solution is not yet available
                {
                    none = true;
                    break;
                }
                end = (start + 1) % N;
                cur_ptr = P[start] - D[start];
            }
            else
            {
                end = (end + 1) % N;
                cur_ptr += P[end] - D[end];
            }
        }
        return none?-1:start;
    }
```